# Prove that if $A^{t}A$ is idempotent then $A^{t}=A^{+}$

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, pseudoinverse

Let $A_{m\times{n}}$ 
prove that if $A^{t}A$ is idempotent, then  $A^{t}=A^{+}$.

I already proved the reciprocal, but I am having some troubles with this one. I think that I have to prove that the 4 conditions of the Moore-Penrose inverse holds. I would like to know if my prove is correct.

My attempt:
Because $A^{t}A$ is idempotent, then
$A^{t}AA^{t}A=A^{t}A$ $\hspace{1cm}$ associating we have

$(A^{t}AA^{t})A=A^{t}A$

Then $A^{t}AA^{t}=A^{t}$

Is this correct? To prove that $AA^{t}A=A$ is analogous. And to prove that $AA^{t}$ and $A^{t}A$ is symmetric is a property already proved and I can use it.

My question is: what property guarentees that if $(A^{t}AA^{t})A=A^{t}A$ then $A^{t}AA^{t}=A^{t}$ ?

Comment: Why is the title different from the question? Anyway, you cannot generally pass from $AX=BX$ to $A=B$, so your simplification is invalid.

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake in the question.

Comment: What is $A^+$ ?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire is the Moore-Penrose inverse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B=AA^TA$. Then $B^TB=A^TA=A^TB$. It follows that $\|B\|_F^2=\|A\|_F^2=\langle A,B\rangle$ and in turn, $\langle A,B\rangle=\|A\|_F\|B\|_F$. Hence $A=B=AA^TA$. Take transposes on both sides, we also get $A^T=A^TAA^T$.

Comment: What does that F in the subscript mean?

Comment: @ManuelVargas It is the standard notation for Frobenius norm, the matrix norm induced by [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product).

Comment: Why I can say that if $\langle A,B\rangle=\|A\|_F\|B\|_F$ then $A=B$?

Comment: @ManuelVargas Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following facts

1. $\mathcal{R}(A^tA)=\mathcal{R}(A)$
2. Fact 1 and that $A^tA$ is idempotent implies that $A^tA$ is a projector onto $\mathcal{R}(A)$

Hence $(A^tA)A^t=A^t$.